# Add a Text Field to A UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm trying to dynamically add textfields when a button is clicked.

I thought that the easiest way would be to have an initial table view and then dynamically add new cells which contain a text field.

However, when I add a new cell - the text field is showing 2 cells underneath - I cant work out what I'm doing wrong..

```
// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("in delegte table view")
    return createTableRow()    
}

func createTableRow() -> UITableViewCell{

     let cell:UITableViewCell = self.extraGuestsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

     cell.textLabel?.text = "some text"

     let tf = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 20))
     tf.placeholder = "Enter text here"
     tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)


     //cell.contentView.addSubview(tf)
     cell.addSubview(tf)

    return cell
}
```

How can I make the textfield appear in the correct table view cell?
Thanks

EDIT

Thanks all - the problem, as a few people pointed out, was that the y position was set to 100 - therefore showing beneath the cell.
It should be:

```
let tf = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text field frame should be with in cell size and check your datasource also

use

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(tf)
```

instead of `cell.addSubview(tf)`

The default height is 44, if you want more then implement respective delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
```

add code at last

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Then change your code:

```
let cell: customCell = self.extraGuestsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as customCell!


 let tf = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 300, height: 20))
 tf.placeholder = "Enter text here"
 tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)


 //cell.contentView.addSubview(tf)
 cell.addSubview(tf)

return cell
```

Comment: I've already tried that, its currently commented out, but it doesn't fix it

Comment: What is your cell height? you are giving y position 100? create custom cell and use it.

Comment: I actually haven't set a cell height - as the cells are dynamic - the code above is all there is, there is nothing in storyboard. Also the datasource is simply an empty array:  var tableData =  [String]()

Comment: return some count number in your datasource and check

Comment: use custom cell